# How to communicate without prior knowledge of IP

Tags: android, tcp, network-programming

Im developing an app which uses the **tcp** connection. currently im communicating using hard coded IP addresses as a sample, but in the real world this is not the case i think. We come across any mobile and start communicating/sharing etc without having any prior knowledge of other person's IP. 
 In such a case how to get the IP address of those who are using my application. How can i communicate without the prior knowledge of the IP address. How to implement this. Help me in sorting it.
 Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
And in case if the user connects the internet thro' GPRS/3G connection then his IP address will be changing based on the service provider. How can i find that.

Comment: Are you trying to connect your users through the Internet or is it enough to connect them on the local LAN (with WIFI for example)?

Comment: @Alejandro Mezcua: Im trying to connect the user thro' internet.

Comment: You should _really_ learn the basics of computer networking. Comparing TCP and DNS only shows that you have a bigger problem than what you have asked in the question.

Comment: @Octavian: Maybe im not good in networking,but i need to start with this. So i started learning the basic stuff. provide me some ideas to move towards the app. (Some samples for android and procedures to start with,etc..).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given what you are commenting on other answers, if what you want are the IP addresses of other Android devices to do some kind of P2P game you should note that there is no reliable way to do that directly.

If the users are connected in the same LAN you could provide in your application some kind of discovery service using UDP broadcasts.

If the users are connected to the internet and have public IP addresses then you could use some intermediate server to register the users at startup and have them discover other users using that server.

But (and this is the most common case) if the users are connected to the Internet and have private IP addresses (like when they are connected with WIFI on their LAN) you need some kind of server that acts as a proxy for their requests because there is no way to make a direct TCP connection from a natted IP to another natted IP. There are a few solutions to solve this problem, you could start for example by learning something about XMPP and how it works.

Comment: thanks for your help. U mentioned some intermediate server,can u elaborate on that. Thanks again

Comment: Not really because it greatly depends on your application and protocol. I'd first take a look at how others do it so that you can learn and the adapt your app to whatever setup you think is best for your application.

Answer (score 1):

Your app must use DNS. You will first need get your IP into the DNS system. You do this by signing up for a domain name & setting up A / AAAA records for hostnames with a hosting provider (or you could set up your own DNS server). You may even find some free DNS providers.

In your app, you can hard-code a fully qualified domain name that you previously set up, say - app.foo.com and use the android gethostbyname library call to fetch the IP address for you. The local DNS resolver will then go to its DNS server and fetch the IP address corresponding to app.foo.com.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use DNS? You can still hard-code the domain name if you want, and the domain name can be configured to point to any IP addresses anytime later.

Comment: Wats the advantage of using DNS over TCP. then how can i know who all are using my app using DNS. Wats the procedure. Can u give some code samples which explain this. Thanks